# CSS: Three boxes such that smaller box is inside the bigger box which is inside the biggest box

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I came across a coding question where I had to create three boxes one inside the other. Below is my code. As of now it only creates two boxes. What changes should I make in my code to include the third box.

```css
#first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#first #second {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25%;
  background: black;
}

#first #second #third {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="first">
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#second {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#third {
  width: 12.5px;
  height: 12.5px;
  margin-top: 18.75px;
  margin-left: 18.75px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="first">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="third">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks and how do I perfectly position the innermost box at the center?

Comment: There, I did my best

Comment: Well I can't see it cause I'm using a phone

Comment: Got it, you will have to put it in the center yourself.

Comment: Thanks again, this helps me to understand the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to place the `#third` div inside `#second` div. Try placing it inside the second one. Try this one.

```
<body>
  <div id="first">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="third"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of `css` rather `html`.

```
<div id="first">
 <div id="second">
    <div id="third"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

In the code above. `Third` is the child of `Second` and `Second` is child of `First`.